# Left menu doesn't move when I use jquery.easing.1.3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use jquery.easing.1.3.js library to make menu left moves from top to bottom parent element itselt as advertisements (left, right) in this page http://baogiadientu.com/demo/banner/index.html (firefox browse recommend). I've used this code for new site but It's not working:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $banner=$('.banner');
            $window=$(window);
            $topDefault=parseFloat($banner.css('top'), 10);
            $window.scroll(function(){
                $top=$(this).scrollTop();
                $banner.stop().animate({top: $top+$topDefault}, 1000, 'easeOutCirc');
            });

            $wiBanner=$banner.outerWidth()*2;
            zindex($('#col-left').outerWidth());
            $window.resize(function(){
                zindex($('#col-left').outerWidth());
            })
            function zindex(maxWidth){
                if($window.width() <= maxWidth+$wiBanner){
                    $banner.addClass('zindex');
                }else{
                    $banner.removeClass('zindex');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

This is new site, please use firebug to see code: http://baogiadientu.com/demo/home/news.php (color left menu below logo's site). Thanks so much!

Comment: I dont see `jquery.easing.1.3.js` library script in your http://baogiadientu.com/demo/home/news.php

Comment: I put it in bottom of page :)